# Finds the optimal cross-validated L1-penalty for a given L2-penalty

Tags: c++, r, cross-validation

I have a list of vectors (each vector is a *variable*) which values can be 0 or 1, and this values represent the coefficient (a1, a2, ...) of my models:

```
y = x1 * a1 + x2 * a2 ...
```

I need to use cross-validation to build a Poisson regression model that balances model fit with complexity by pushing variable coefficients towards zero; in order to reduce the large set of variables to a smaller set of variables with non-zero coefficients.

I know that this result can be obtained with the [penalized R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html), but I am wondering if it could be done by using any C++ library.

Comment: Your language is quite unclear for SO.  E.g. "each vector is a variable" makes no sense. "cross-validation" is not a programming term either.